# Get the longest length words and remove the \n after each string?

Tags: python

```
f = open('wordlist.txt','w')
for x in range(4):
    u = input('please enter how many words you like to write')
    f.write(u + '\n') 
print('it have been wrote into file')


e = 0
y = 0               #y for total length
f = open('wordlist.txt','r')

for x in f:
    print(len(x))
    y += len(x)
    e += 1
    if len(x) >= len(x):
         z = len(x)       #get largest length
    
avglength = y/e          #get average length for each line

print(z)            
print(y)
print(avglength)
```

as the code above, i want to get the largest length in file but its only get me the length of last word, why is that happening? and how to remove the '\n' after each string which i need to find each word length but the length is incorrect. For example, the 'sss' is supposed to have length of 3 and in my code i added '\n' each line, this may causing the 'sss' is having the length of 4. any helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write in your code:

```
if len(x) >= len(x):
     z = len(x)
```

which is always going to be `True`. As a result your `z` will take the length value of your last `x`, which will be your last word.

You could keep track of your current maximum length, by outside of the for loop define a max_length variable:

`max_length = 0`

and in the loop use:

```
max_length = max([len(x), max_length])
if len(x) >= max_length:
    z = len(x)
    max_length = z
```

Or as you pointed out in the comments below you could simply write this entire statement as:

```
z = max([len(x), z])
```

provided you have set `z = 0` outside of the `for` loop.

Here is a slightly modified way of doing the calculations you want. It might be easier to read, and it uses the context manager `with` to handle opening and closing your file:

```
# get words and write to file
with open('wordlist.txt','w') as f:
    for x in range(4):
        u = input('please enter a word: ')
        f.write(u + '\n')
    print('Your words have been written into the file')
    
# read words and count find length of longest word
with open('wordlist.txt') as f:
    words = f.readlines()
word_lengths = [len(i.strip()) for i in words]    # get the length of each word in list after removing white space
max_length = max(word_lengths)            # find the longest length
total_length = sum(word_lengths)          # find the total length of all words
average_word_length = total_length / len(words)   # find the average length
```

Comment: thank you @robbo. so what about my second question about the length of string? its didn't give me the correct length like 'one' is supposed to have length of 3 but its give me a 4? how can i fixe that? it is because i added '\n' at the end of that string?

Comment: @MINO See my answer, it covers everything. Thanks

Comment: @MINO sorry, yes didn't address that because another answer had that covered. You can use `strip()` to get rid off all the white space on either side of the word. Which would remove the new line character. So when you write `for x in f:` make the next line `x = x.strip()`

Comment: @robbo in your second code, what does it do  in ```line of max_length = max([len(x), max_length])? ```can you get rid of it? i found out you can still get longest length without that line with just ```max_length = 0   if len(x) >= max_length: z = len(x) max_length = z```

Comment: @MINO The `max()` function returns the maximum value of a list (hence the square brackets). Yes you're right, you can get rid of that line. But on the other hand, you can also keep the line and get rid of the `if` statement if you use `max_length` as your final variable, rather than `z`. I think the latter is a bit more elegant even.  I've updated the code above by getting rid of `max_length` and calling it `z` instead. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
# Use open() as a context manager so you don't have to worry about closing the file.
with open('wordlist.txt','r') as opened:
    # Create a list of words in the file.
    # words = list(opened)

    # EDIT: The traditional way to split some lines and strip
    # the newline character.
    words = opened.read().strip().split("\n")

    # Start max_length at negative 1.
    max_length = -1

    # List object to hold all word lengths.
    all_lengths = []

    # Number of words written to file
    num_of_words = len(words)

    # Iterate the list of words.
    for word in words:
        # Get length of the current word.
        current_length = len(word)

        # Append the length of the current word to the list.
        all_lengths.append(current_length)

        # Using all_lengths[-1] gets the latest item on the list
        # Also, we only care if the current value is larger than the max value.
        if all_lengths[-1] > max_length:
            max_length = all_lengths[-1]

# Average length of word per line.
average_length = sum(all_lengths) / num_of_words
```

Comment: thanks @Mark Moretto so what about my second question about the length of string? its didn't give me the correct length like 'one' is supposed to have length of 3 but its give me a 4? how can i fixe that? it is because i added '\n' at the end of that string?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.split()` method to remove `\n` from your string.

Here is what you have to do:

```
x = x.split('\n')
    x = x[0]
```

You can add this in `for x in f:` loop.

**Here is the full code:**

```
f = open('wordlist.txt', 'w')
for x in range(4):
    u = input('Please enter the word: ')
    f.write(u + '\n')
print('it has been written into file')

z = 0
e = 0
y = 0  # y for total length
f = open('wordlist.txt', 'r')

for x in f:
    x = x.split('\n')    #Now, x = ['Your Input', '']
    x = x[0]             #Select first string
    print(len(x))
    y += len(x)
    e += 1
    if len(x) >= z:
        z = len(x)  # get largest length

avglength = y / e  # get average length for each line

print(z)
print(y)
print(avglength)
```

**Here is the run:**

```
Please enter the word: This
Please enter the word: is
Please enter the word: just
Please enter the word: testing
```

**Respective Output:**

```
4
2
4
7
7
17
4.25
```